# How could Nolan Sorrento move in the Oasis like that if he was in the chair in reality?

Tags: ready-player-one-2018

In *Ready Player One (2018)*, we can see Nolan Sorrento doing bunch of "wild" moves in the Oasis, e.g. fighting against Parzival. How could he do such a moves if he was **sitting in the Habashoo 9400 chair**? Even walking would be almost impossible while sitting there.

[image]

Comment: I modified your tag to reference the film as opposed to the book. Quick answer. We don't know. Watching the scenes I could find on Youtube show that the chair is actually pretty basic. The middle "seems" designed only for comfort and the foot platform just to rest your feet. The only real controls seem to be near the hands. Without knowing the actual design we can only surmise that the "handholds" are also kind of like joysticks and that some finger controls/combinations, possibly combined with the chair/visor interface, enable the more complex motions observed.

Comment: i.e. https://resource.supercheats.com/library/300w/mortal-kombat-x/subzero_sp1A.jpg

Comment: Seems like you are right. Also seems pretty unfair to me, as he was only using some kind of joystick while others had to really perform the moves to achieve what they want to do (in e.g. combat).

Comment: Well, you also have to remember. It is all dependent upon your interface. Some just use gloves and a visor; still able to achieve their full range of motion. Wade had the fancy suit that allowed him to feel everything, but likely made tracking his movements easier. Nolan's is likely an expensive interface that maximizes comfort and ease of use with a high grade/ simple command setup. While I am sure the OASIS is pretty important in granting the movement you are attempting the more advanced/intuitive your setup is the better results you'll get.

Comment: But of course the key thing to remember is that it is not real... yet (fingers crossed). The Omni directional pad would be great for speed and even pressure could determine jump height and etc., but for someone without it (like the businessman in the film who died on Doom) you would need some serious software to control your entire body's movements with only some gloves and goggles. I'm not fully convinced it isn't possible, but we are most definitely not there yet in real life, IMO.

Answer (score -2):

Possibly has some sort of basic early version of an brain interface? Probably not but you never know. We know that in *Ready Player Two* (terrible book ik) they have a sort of brain interface. So maybe IOI had an early test version and Sorento used it for himself.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This seems very speculative, and somewhat contradicts the idea that Aitch and Zee could control Sorrento's environment just by hacking his rig.  Do you have any evidence for this?  Obviously his goggles worked like normal goggles, and there wasn't any visual evidence of another hook-up.